# C# ASP.NET MVC ERROR IN RETURNING VALUES IN VIEW

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, actionresult

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project and I want to return to the view `GuardarRegistro` three controller values, these values are `IdSucursal`, `IdProducto`, `Cantidad`, but I get an error saying that

`CS1501 C # No overload for method 'View' takes 4 arguments`

This is the code of the controller where the error appears

```
public ActionResult Nuevo(decimal IdSucursal = 0, decimal IdProducto = 0, decimal Cantidad = 0)
{
    new RegistroAlmacenAdmin().GuardarRegistro(IdSucursal, IdProducto, Cantidad);
    ViewBag.mensaje = "registro de almacen guardado";
    return View("GuardarRegistro", IdSucursal, IdProducto, Cantidad);//CS1501 error in this line in word view
}
```

I was planning to create a new object inside the `ActionResult` but I don't know how to do it right

Comment: View method  accepts view name and the model class object. You need to learn how to create object of a class. And then pass that object to the view method as second argument. Object of class can be created by doing `var obj = new <<Class name>>();`. More can be read [here](https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-class-object.html) and [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-passing-data-from-controller-to-view/)

Comment: As arleady said you have to wrap IdSucursal, IdProducto, Cantidad in a class (viewModel) and pass it to View(...)

Answer (score 0):

Goodnight
Thank you very much for the comments and the articles that helped me find an answer, I understand better oop, the answer code is as follows

model

```
public partial class RegistroAlmacen
{
    public decimal IdRegistro { get; set; }
    public decimal IdSucursal { get; set; }
    public decimal IdProducto { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }

    public virtual Producto Producto { get; set; }
    public virtual Sucursal Sucursal { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Nuevo(decimal IdSucursal=0, decimal IdProducto=0, decimal Cantidad=0)
    {
        RegistroAlmacen objeto = new RegistroAlmacen
        {
            IdSucursal=IdSucursal,
            IdProducto = IdProducto,
            Cantidad=Cantidad
        };
        new RegistroAlmacenAdmin().GuardarRegistro(IdSucursal, IdProducto, Cantidad);
        ViewBag.mensaje = "registro de almacen guardado";
        return View("GuardarRegistro", objeto);
    }
```